# Win11 22H2 Programmatically switch between predefined power modes (Best power efficiency/Balanced/Best performance)

Tags: c++, windows-11

How do you programmatically switch between predefined power modes (Best power efficiency/Balanced/Best performance) in **Win11 22H2**?

Is this still possible given that Microsoft is now removing all Sleep/Screen off overrides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Powercfg command-line options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options)

Setting the "Super performance" scheme active:

```
powercfg /setactive ac093644-6503-4314-b3b6-0b601924e3e9
```

A detailed tutorial can be found here:
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-powercfg-control-power-settings-windows-10

And of course, you can set all values in the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings
```